# display records for each date between the range

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display records for each date from database for the range of dates provided by the user.
i.e if the user specifies 2012-july-2 to 2012-july-4.
then 
the output has to be

```
date:2012-july-02  
name | intime | outtime |Teamtype

date:2012-july-03
name | intime | outtime |Teamtype  

so on..
```

SQL for this :

```sql
 $s="SELECT InDate,mstEmp.cardnofrom mstEmp left join dailyattendance ON (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' ) AND(dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname ) where teamtype='$chk'";
$objDB->SetQuery($s);
$r = $objDB->GetQueryReference();

 $sql= SELECT mstEmp.empname,   
       mstEmp.cardno, 
       InDate, 
       dailyattendance.InTime,
       dailyattendance.OutTime, 
       mstEmp.teamtype            
FROM mstEmp  
 LEFT JOIN dailyattendance    
 ON (InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')  AND (dailyattendance.HolderName =mstEmp.empname )   
WHERE mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk' 
ORDER BY InDate DESC
$res = $objDB->GetQueryReference();
```

What I tried is

```
  <!-- language: lang-php -->

    while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($r) )
  {

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        list($name, $crd,$indate,$in,$out,$t) = $row;
        if($rw[1]!=$crd && $row[2]=='')
        {
            $d1='NULL';
            $d2='NULL';
        }
        else
        {
        $d1 = date("g:i A", $in);
        $d2 = date("g:i A" ,$out);
        $d3 = date("d-m-Y (D)", $in);
        $bg = '';
        if(date('D', $in) == 'Sun' || date('D', $in) == 'Sat')
        $bg = 'bgcolor=#EEEEEE';
        else 
        $bg = 'bgcolor= #ECE5B6';
        if ($ddate != $row[2])
        {   
            echo "<tr $bg><td colspan=4>Date: ".$d3."</td></tr>";
            $ddate = $row[2];
        }
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=left width='35%'>".trim($name)."</td>";
        echo "<td align=center width='20%' >".$d1."</td>";
        echo "<td align=center  width='23%' >".$d2."</td>";
        echo "<td align=center width='16%'>".$t."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
  echo "</table><br>";
  echo "</form>";
  }

mysql_free_result($res);
mysql_free_result($r);
```

Comment: i m getting the records but records with null value .i.e if that employee is absent for entir erange only then his feilds are shown null and no other employee record if null for any date is not shown

Comment: if($rw[1]!=$crd && $row[2]=='') Here is typo error it should be "if($row[1]!=$crd && $row[2]=='')".

Comment: echo your query and run in your database, LEFT JOIN error may come.

Comment: What's the datatype oft the date fields?

Comment: @Himani I have just suggested you, its not my answer :)

Comment: @Rohit yes the error is there now what query sholud i use then

Comment: @Himani Have you tried the answer posted by "Puggan Se"?

Comment: ya..it is not showing me any null value

Comment: ans anyone? i need it immediately

Comment: can you post code before this list($name, $crd,$indate,$in,$out,$t) = $row;

Comment: i added fruther info to the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you filter for days should belong in `WHERE` insted of `ON`

```
SELECT
 mstEmp.empname,
 mstEmp.cardno,
 InDate,
 dailyattendance.InTime,
 dailyattendance.OutTime,
 mstEmp.teamtype
FROM mstEmp
LEFT JOIN dailyattendance
  ON (dailyattendance.HolderName = mstEmp.empname )
WHERE
  mstEmp.teamtype = '$chk' AND
  InDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
ORDER BY
  InDate DESC
```